# CoreData - How to do NSFetchRequest with temporary context with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType?

Tags: iphone, performance, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Since iOS 5, CoreData introduces its own `private queue` where you can let some operations (`especially save context`) running in background.

This must be done via `[context performBlock:...]`.

It is easy very good for `saving the context`. However, how about for `NSFetchRequest`? I mean what if I want to fetch something and wish to fetch in the background? I don't think [context performBlock..] can achieve this.

Is there also a new way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that involves the `NSManagedObjectContext` of `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` should be wrapped in a `performBlock` block.  For background fetching where you want to pass managed objects back to the main queue's context, something like this:  (note this is just for illustrative purposes):

```
// assume self.managedObjectContext is a main queue context
NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[backgroundContext performBlock:^{
    // do your fetch - e.g. executeFetchRequest
    NSManagedObjectID *objID = [someManagedObject objectID];
    [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        NSManagedObject *mainManagedObject = [self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:objID];
        //  do something now with this managed object in the main context
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to background fetch a nsresultscontroller and let it be used by the main UI?